# HTML Helper to jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SingleListing.ListingTitle)`
Let's Say on Execution the html helper gives a value of xxx , i need to pass this xxx into a jQuery script. Possible ?
PS : I prefer not use it in input hidden tag and the HTML helper is not going to be used anywhere else in the view.

Comment: you can always pass the value via the model

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are calling a js on that .cshtml which is binded to model..

lets say you are calling some function add..

you could always use

```
$(document).ready(function()){
  var Addfunction = function(DisplayName){
      //Do some stuff with the Display Name
 }
```

you can then call the AddFunction in the script with the model param

```
 <script>  
   Addfunction('@Model.SingleListing')  //remember  the '
 </script>
```

Comment: Hey , can i know what '  Addfunction('@Model.SingleListing') ' means exactly ?? And how do i extract ListTitle from the model at jquery.. @Rohitas Behera